# Get input function from another .smk file in SnakeMake

Tags: rules, snakemake

I have stored my SnakeMake rules in different `.smk` files. I have one file (a.smk) with following input function

```
def get_input(wildcards):
   # Some processing
   return input_list

rule some_rule_in_first_file:
   input: get_input
   # rest of the rule
```

Now in another file (b.smk) I want to do something like following,

```
rule another_rule_in_second_file:
   input: get_input 
   # Rest of the rule
```

How can I achieve above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use the [include](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/modularization.html#includes) directive. I.e., in your `b.smk` you should add something like:

```
include: '/path/to/a.smk'
```